Using multiple labels in an align and aligned environment
I've got four equations, split into two groups, and I want to label them accordingly using:
\begin{align}
\text{Group 1} &\left\{
\begin{aligned}
   &y=x, \label{eqn:eqn_1} \\
   &y=z, \label{eqn:eqn_2}
\end{aligned}
\right.\\
\text{Group 2} &\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    &y=2x, \label{eqn:eqn_3} \\
    &y=2z \label{eqn:eqn_4}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}

But I'm getting the error
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eqn:eqn_1' will be lost. 

The only options I've found online is to label each aligned with just one label, but I'm looking for a solution that allows all 4 equations to have distinct labels.

Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Use, for example, empheq and subequations enviroments.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:group1}
\text{Group 1}\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
   &y=x, \label{eqn:eqn_1}\\
   &y=z, \label{eqn:eqn_2}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:group2}
\text{Group 2}\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    &y=2x, \label{eqn:eqn_3}\\
    &y=2z, \label{eqn:eqn_4}
\end{empheq}
\quad
\end{subequations}

Equations \eqref{eqn:eqn_1}, \eqref{eqn:eqn_2}, \eqref{eqn:eqn_3}, and \eqref{eqn:eqn_4} belong to the groups specified in \eqref{eqn:group1} and \eqref{eqn:group2}.

\end{document}


